# Copy file with FOR /F %I IN () DO (copy) command, file contain space

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd, command-line

I want to copy a file with a whitespace in the filename; how do I do this via `For` loop:

```bat
For /F %I in ('Dir "D:\Temp\temp 1.cs" /B /O:-D') do (Copy "D:\Temp\%I" "D:\temp2\")
```

- Per business requirements, it should be done via a `For` loop, as I know this works:

  ```bat
  Copy "D:\Temp\temp 1.cs" "D:\temp2\"
  ```

Comment: What is the `linux` tag for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `delims` with `|` worked for me:

```bat
For /F "delims=|" %I in ('Dir "D:\Temp\temp*1.cs" /B /O:-D') do (Copy "D:\Temp\%I"  "D:\temp2\")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set [`delims`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to an empty string:

```bat
For /F "delims=" %X in ('Dir /B') do @ECHO %X
```